# Webpack not found, deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, heroku

very new to Node and deploying to Heroku. I have a basic React app set up and am attempting to deploy to Heroku. I have it pushed, but the app is failing. When I look at the logs I see something about `sh: 1: webpack: not found` (full log [here](https://gist.github.com/kimispencer/ac6070060daf82d2e421f95574c439f2))

I'm not really certain what's going on, but believe it has something to do with my package.json? From the starter template I am using it is as such:

```
{
    "name": "express-react-redux-starter",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Starter for Express, React, Redux, SCSS applications",
    "scripts": {
      "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack/webpack-dev.config.js --watch --colors",
      "build": "rm -rf dist && webpack --config ./webpack/webpack-prod.config.js --colors",
      "start": "PORT=8080 node start ./server.js",
      "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
      "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
      "lint": "eslint src test webpack"
    },
    "keywords": [
      "ExpressJS",
      "ReactJS",
      "Redux",
      "React hot loader",
      "React Router",
      "SCSS",
      "Webpack Devevelopment configuration",
      "Webpack Production configuration",
      "Airbnb Eslint",
      "pm2",
      "mocha",
      "chai"
    ],
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git+https://github.com/DimitriMikadze/express-react-redux-starter"
    },
    "author": "Dimitri Mikadze",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "^6.4.0",
      "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
      "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
      "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
      "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
      "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
      "chai": "^3.5.0",
      "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
      "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
      "eslint": "^2.10.2",
      "eslint-config-airbnb": "^9.0.1",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.8.0",
      "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.2.0",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.1.1",
      "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
      "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.16.1",
      "jquery": "^2.2.3",
      "jsdom": "^9.0.0",
      "mocha": "^2.4.5",
      "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
      "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.0.2",
      "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
      "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
      "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
      "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
      "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "classnames": "^2.2.5",
      "express": "^4.13.4",
      "lodash": "^4.15.0",
      "react": "^15.0.2",
      "react-dom": "^15.0.2",
      "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
      "react-router": "^2.4.0",
      "redux": "^3.5.2",
      "webpack": "^1.13.0"
    }
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly to get this deployed? Works great on my localhost. But cannot figure out how to get this up into the world for the life of me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Ok -- this has to do with devDependencies vs. Dependencies in package.json
Also, by setting the Heroku config to `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION: false` I was able to resolve this. Thx internet!

Comment: NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION: false, why would you do this?  By default heroku will install dependencies and not devDependencies.  Also webpack dev server is not meant for production.

Comment: heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false is the syntax for this suggestion.

Comment: Spend 2.5 hours to check and double check, until realized that webpack was devDependencies so after push to slug it was pruned and nothing was builld. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Heroku's documentation states "By default, Heroku will install all dependencies listed in package.json under dependencies and devDependencies." (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation) Is this outdated or simply wrong?

Comment: @DanielM According to my tests, it seems like that piece of doc is true for the main folder. Assume having server code at root with express and babel. In deployment, all deps are installed and the server compiles succesfully. The problem appears when you switch folder to do another install + build (like `cd client && npm install && npm run build). This is the case where the install goes against the docs and installs only production deps. Adding the --dev flag did fix the issue for me; check out my repo [here](https://github.com/DefJunx/secret-santa) for a practical example.

Comment: Its answers like this one that make sure I'll always have a job in security :')

Answer (score 26):

As others have said, Heroku runs node as production `NODE_ENV=production`, which means your devDependencies don't get installed. Heroku provides node specific build hooks though. I use `heroku-prebuild` to run `npm install --dev`, which installs all dependencies and devDependencies.

```
"scripts": {
  ...,
  "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --dev",
  ...
},
```

Running your app NOT in production mode should probably be avoided. Often developers have "dev mode" specific code that will get filtered out when running in production. Plus if you're doing things a webpack build you definitely want to be in production mode to take advantage of minification, uglifying, etc.

Here's the details from Heroku.

> Sometimes, developers need something more production-oriented than the
>   preinstall and postinstall hooks in package.json. For instance, some
>   apps need to set up extra authentication before installing
>   dependencies. Some need to build assets, but not in a development
>   environment. Further examples can be found in the discussion on
>   GitHub.
>
> Node.js developers can now use heroku-prebuild and heroku-postbuild
>   hooks to tailor the build process to their apps.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/844

Comment: Yes @thisismydesign, it goes in the "scripts" section of `package.json`

Comment: Although it doesn't make much sense still. You don't want dev-dependencies in production, you just want to run webpack.

Answer (score 13):

This happens because heroku by default doesn't install dev Dependencies of package.json, we need to exculsively tell heroku (npm) to install our dev dependencies (webpack is in dev), so running this command should solve the 
"not found issue"

.

```
npm install --dev
```

Comment: This is a much better solution.

Answer (score 3):

What's causing this is `devDependencies` are not installed. You overcome this by typing the following command in your project's root dir:

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

Then, the next time you deploy your app your issue should be resolved.

Comment: Though that will install the devDependencies, deploying the app NOT in production might lead to other issues. What really needs to happen is you need to tell heroku to install the devDependencies which can be done using their `heroku-prebuild` script in your package.json file (see my answer).

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood the problem so her for yarn users:

```
"heroku-prebuild": "yarn install --production=false"
```

The problem is not the pruning that happens afterwards according to the docu (for npm at least) but yarn interpreting NODE_ENV and only installing production dependencies even in the pre-build phase.

To force yarn to "oversee" the env variable you have to give the `--production=false` flag. see https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/

**Note** as mentioned in the comments installing dev dependencies in production is never a good idea. This is only meaningful for ruling out deployment issues.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. Many dev dependencies become vulnerabilities in production.

Answer (score 1):

This is what it worked for me https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/512

heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs

Comment: This solved my issue as well when I updated Rails 4.2.8 to 6.1.4

Answer (score 0):

This behavior changed on 01.03.2018: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1376

It will install `devDependencies` but also prune them as part of deploy. Pruning can be skipped via `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`. This still leaves `NODE_ENV` set to `production`.

Answer (score -1):

Like others have said, Heroku will prune devDependencies before running the specified package.json script to spin up the app.

I would still like Heroku to prune devDependencies since those packages are not actively needed while in production, only in the build process. Heroku allows for a [customized build process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) which I was able to leverage to achieve the desired effect.

```
"scripts": {
  "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --dev",
  "build": "webpack --mode production",
  "start": "node src/app.js",
}
```

The pre-build will install dev dependencies, then the build script will simply use those dev dependencies to generate the webpack bundles. After which the devDependencies will be pruned regularly for production right before running the start script.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. Many dev dependencies become vulnerabilities in production.